# table having two columns referencing to single column of another table

Tags: mysql

I have a table `student_detal(id,name,class)` and one more table `sibling_detail(sid references to student(id),siblingid references to student(id))`.
The entries of `student` table are
[image]

sibling of id 1 is id 3 and 4, 
so the entries of sibling detail table should be

```
sid       siblingid
1             3
1             4
3             1
4             1
```

but I want to prevent the insertion of 3rd and 4th row as their detail is already inserted in first two rows. How can i do this?

Comment: There's no built-in way to do this constraint. You could use a trigger that checks for existing rows and signals an error.

Comment: How about you make sure sid is always less than siblingid before you insert? That way 3rd and 4th inserts will try to insert (1, 3) and (1, 4) and it will fail due to unique constraint.